# Accepting polymorphic associations through checkbox in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, polymorphic-associations

I have got a Products class,Products are visible to zero or many roles. So, I have created a polymorphic model called content_roles,which stores the id of the role and content_id (which will be product_id,or event_id),and content_type(product,event etc).

I am using nested_form gem for accepting the role id(using check_box) to store the product and role relation in content_role

I get an error no implicit conversion of String into Integer in Products#create function

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdLH99ZWLrf8dgT3gcBops=", "product"=>{"product_name"=>"some product", "product_description"=>"some product description", "content_roles_attributes"=>{"role_id"=>["1", "2", ""]}}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}

in my view I have written

```
 = f.simple_fields_for :content_roles_attributes do |role|
  = role.input :role_id,label: "visible to", as: :check_boxes,label: "Role",collection: Role.all,:required=>true
```

the controllers permitted params looks like

```
def create
 #Getting the error at this line
 @product = Product.new(product_params)
 respond_to do |format|
  if @product.save  
end

def product_params
 params.require(:product).permit(:product_description,:product_name,
 content_roles_attributes:  [:id,role_id: []],
 multimedia_attributes:[:asset,:_destroy,:id])
end
```

the product model looks like:

```
class Product     
  has_many :content_roles, as: :content
  has_many :multimedia ,as: :storable
  # Nested attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :multimedia
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :content_roles
 end
```

and this is the content_role model

```
class ContentRole < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true
 belongs_to :role
 belongs_to :news
 belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: @Surya I have updated my question .you can have look at it

Comment: change `product_params` code to this: `params.require(:product).permit(:product_description,:product_name,
 content_roles_attributes:  [:id, :role_id],
 multimedia_attributes:[:asset,:_destroy,:id])` and then try again.

Comment: Also, in params, role_id should not be an array since you have belongs to for role, so it should be something like this: `"content_roles_attributes"=>{"role_id"=>"1"}`